# Use of Over() and Partition By returns NULL in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, window-functions

I have used following query

```
 select  distinct max( MONITORING_INT)  over(partition by  PATIENT_ADM_ID) Interval
 from PATIENT_PART
 where PATIENT_ADM_ID=1466;
```

and it returns `456`.

The query with problematic output is as following

```
SELECT DISTINCT lv.NAME AS Delivery_Mode,
  pp.DELIVERY_DATETIME,


  pp.LAST_PV_EXAMINATION_DATE ,
  max( pp.MONITORING_INT)  over(partition by  pp.PATIENT_ADM_ID) Interval
FROM PATIENT_PART pp
LEFT JOIN LOOKUP_VALUES lv
ON lv.id=pp.DELIVERY_MODE_ID
WHERE pp.PATIENT_ADM_ID=1466;
```

**Output**

```
Delivery_Mode DELIVERY_DATETIME                  LAST_PV_EXAMINATION_DATE        Interval 
 SVD          22-APR-19 12.00.00.000000000 AM    25-APR-19 12.00.00.000000000 AM   (null)
```

but when I use the same `max()` and `over()` functionality in `select` list here in above mentioned query it returns `null`. Please let me know the reason!

Comment: In first query you have `where patient_adm_id = 1466`, in second `patient_admission_id = 1466`. Do you have two different columns?

Comment: Is it `pp.PATIENT_ADM_ID` or `pp.patient_admission_id`? You have a difference in your second query

Comment: It's the same. Please ignore.

Comment: I have edited the query as well

Comment: @MuhammadWaheed . . . The `left join` should not be changing the value of the expression.  Can you reproduce this in a db<>fiddle?